# Wifi Direct in Windows 7 and WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7, wifi-direct

I would like to have some basic communication between some apps we are building. I have been researching on wifi direct, which sounds perfect, but I cannot find much information on it for Windows 7 and WPF (C#).

When I search around all I seem to get is Windows 8 support and Android questions.

Is this a standard that has been implemented by Windows 7? Can I use the features in a C# WPF app? If so, some reference materials would be great if you know of any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi direct is not implemented in Windows 7, although there may be some 3rd party apps available that implement it.

It is a new feature built into windows 8.  Here's a presentation that goes over the feature in detail: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/HW-329T